# Index match Formula Error

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have "master" sheet and a "lists sheet". M2 is an automated value in text (an employees name) being pulled from another cell on same sheet. Now N2 should return the M2 individual's partner name.
To do this, I made two columns on "Lists" sheet for the few employees paired with their partner. The two columns are lead employees (A38:A52) and partners (B38:B52). But when I enter this formula in N2 (SEE BELOW), it is not giving me the true partners names to the employees. How can I fix this? Where am I going wrong?

```
=INDEX(Lists!$B$38:$B$52,MATCH(M2,Lists!$A$38:$A$52),1)
```

Comment: You may need to specify the `match_type` parameter of the `MATCH` function. 'match_type` can be 1, 0, or -1 ("less than", "exact match", or "greater than", respectively). "exact match" is probably what you need. If you use "less than", then $A$38:$A:53 needs to be sorted in ascending order; if "greater than", then descending. You may also be able to use the `VLOOKUP` function instead of `INDEX(...MATCH(...))`, e.g., `VLOOKUP(M2,Lists!$A$38:$B$52,2,FALSE)`.

Comment: Thank you! The v-lookup worked. Is it possible to also have a drop-down list in the same N2 column with a formula. In case, a different partner is working with the employee that day. I have tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: I prefer using Excel Table for convenient naming and `INDEX+MATCH` for better readability (next to `VLOOKUP`). This may not be of matter for ad-hoc spreadsheet, but when you create document you intend to use on regular basis, it would be better for you to take care of readability and naming.

Comment: " it is not giving me the true partners names to the employees." ... what exactly does it gave? (error/otherValue?)